# Найти строку, которая не соответствует паттерну Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Я хочу найти ошибку в библиографическом описании с помощью регулярных выражений. 
У меня есть паттерн
    `(([1-9][0-9]*)\s[с]\S)`
 но я хочу, чтобы матчились те элементы строки, которые не соответствуют данному паттерну.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить все участки строки не соответствующие этой регулярке, можно воспользоваться методом [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
  foreach (string match in substrings)
  {
     Console.WriteLine($"'{match}'");
  }
```

Все соответствия будут благополучно удалены, как разделитель.

Comment: Только шаблон должен быть без захватывающих групп `[1-9][0-9]*\sс\S`